# using numeric keypad to replace English numbers

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been using the below code to replace English numbers with Arabic numbers at run-time, in a new form I only need the numeric keypad to replace the numbers and keep everything else as it is.

Which event should I be using: KeyPress, KeyUp or KeyDown?

How to check and convert KeyCode/KeyChar and vice versa?

And most important is how to achieve the whole idea?

```
private void ArabicNumbers_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyChar)
        {
            case '0': e.KeyChar = '٠'; break;

            case '1': e.KeyChar = '١'; break;

            case '2': e.KeyChar = '٢'; break;

            case '3': e.KeyChar = '٣'; break;

            case '4': e.KeyChar = '٤'; break;

            case '5': e.KeyChar = '٥'; break;

            case '6': e.KeyChar = '٦'; break;

            case '7': e.KeyChar = '٧'; break;

            case '8': e.KeyChar = '٨'; break;

            case '9': e.KeyChar = '٩'; break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you press a key, but still haven’t released it you can see that the character already appeared. Thus you should probably go with OnKeyDown.

Comment: If you put messages in the various down, press and up, you will see that for numbers all 3 can apply, however, you get different options in each stage.

Comment: That didn't answer the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself

```
private bool _isKeyNumPadClick;

private void TxtEdtDocNo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
    {
        _isKeyNumPadClick = true;
    }

    else if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
    {
        _isKeyNumPadClick = false;
    }
}


private void Numbers_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isKeyNumPadClick)
    {
        switch (e.KeyChar)
        {
            case '0': e.KeyChar = '٠'; break;

            case '1': e.KeyChar = '١'; break;

            case '2': e.KeyChar = '٢'; break;

            case '3': e.KeyChar = '٣'; break;

            case '4': e.KeyChar = '٤'; break;

            case '5': e.KeyChar = '٥'; break;

            case '6': e.KeyChar = '٦'; break;

            case '7': e.KeyChar = '٧'; break;

            case '8': e.KeyChar = '٨'; break;

            case '9': e.KeyChar = '٩'; break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (e.KeyChar)
        {
            case '0': e.KeyChar = '0'; break;

            case '1': e.KeyChar = '1'; break;

            case '2': e.KeyChar = '2'; break;

            case '3': e.KeyChar = '3'; break;

            case '4': e.KeyChar = '4'; break;

            case '5': e.KeyChar = '5'; break;

            case '6': e.KeyChar = '6'; break;

            case '7': e.KeyChar = '7'; break;

            case '8': e.KeyChar = '8'; break;

            case '9': e.KeyChar = '9'; break;
        }
    }

    _isKeyNumPadClick = false;
}
```